# What does the row_ptr in Compressed Column Storage representation contain?

Tags: arrays, sparse-matrix, linear-algebra, matrix-storage

I am reading [this](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/4536313/) paper [full text link [here]](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/685b/a0aa422917f7fb2b5dec2d74bb8b451b27c0.pdf) to understand how to store hypersparse matrices. They start off with a discussion of the CSC format. As I understand from netlib the CRS and CSC formats are stored as shown [here](http://netlib.org/linalg/html_templates/node91.html) and [here](http://netlib.org/linalg/html_templates/node92.html#SECTION00931200000000000000).

On page 3 of the paper, they show a diagram of the CSC format taking the example of a 9*9 matrix which is represented in triples format as

A = {(5, 0, 0.1), (7, 0, 0.2)(3, 6, 0.3), (1, 7, 0.4)}

From what I understand, in column-major, this would yield the following arrays :

val = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4];     //value array

IR = [5, 7, 3, 1];              //row indices array

JC = [0, 2, 3, 4];              //column ptrs array (last element is number of nonzero elements)

In the paper, they write the JC array as

JC = [0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4];

I would like to know where the extra '2's come from. Do they represent the empty columns? Apologies for such a basic question but any help appreciated.

Comment: What JC and IR are standing for?